# Fetch app activities of friends from google+

Tags: android, google-plus

I've created an app which post moments/activities of the user to his Google+ page. I can get and list the user's activities on my app. But is it possible to get activities from the user's circles listed on my app instead? I want to do a comparison between the user and his friends based on their app activities. My app is visible to user's circles. I tried following the steps from Google https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/app-activities#list_app_activities but it kept returning me a 400 error, saying unauthorized access even though the app activities are shared with the user's circles. Why?

Answer (score 0):

The Google+ API only lets you fetch Public activities. It will not let you fetch content that's been shared with any other ACL expect Public.